# Block list table (IP, Mac, email, name, username)

Tags: database, data-structures, blocking

I am creating block lists to block user actions based on IP address, MAC address, Email address, Name (first/last name), Trademark names and Usernames. So should each of these be a separate lookup table or can there be one blocked_list table with all these in? Each is individual independent of the other.

The list will be used in few places ->
User signup - block account signup based on IP, MAC, email & any disallowed First/last name
Username creation - block username creation based on restricted usernames
Profile details - block profile email being added based on disallowed emails
Public pages - block people from naming pages based on a restricted list of trademarked names.

Also, is it better to keep this in the DB or a text file? Except trademark names everything else will be in English. For trademarks I may use region specific blocking so need multi-lang support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make each their own table.

how would combining them make your queries run any faster?  it wouldn't.

It isn't like you won't know what you have, if you have a MAC address check in the block MAC address table for it, it would be your primary key which would be defined to the exact proper length and type for a MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

What about having 1 table with all the values in and have a column - block_type. You will need a lookup table for block_type where 1=IP. 2 =MAC,... This was you can manage this with only 2 tables. But I'll let someone more professional answer this as I am new myself to databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the entries in a single table. Check out the Entity-Attribute-Value approach or use a schemaless NoSQL datastore.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

If you're processing the 'blocking' in the middle tier, you can just dump the lists as serialized objects (e.g. JSON) into the table.